# how to return values of multicell named ranges

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

I have some named ranges some are single cell NamedRanges others are multicelled.

When I use `"=AnyNameofSingleCellNamedRange"`  in any cell of the workbook.It returns it's value.

But When I use `"=AnyNameofMultiCellNamedRange"` It returns #VALUE error saying it's of the wrong data type.

Comment: Consider  Multi-celled named range as array of cells and hence use Ctrl+Shift+Enter when using directly or provide in the multi-celled arguments of formula only, for eg. instead of first, it will go in second argument of VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 2):

If you enter =MultiCellNamedRange into a cell on the same row as the range it refers to Excel does an implicit intersection and gives you the value that is the intersection of the named range and the row. if there is no intersection then you get #Value.

If you enter =MultiCellNamedRange as a multicell array formula using Control-shift-Enter then Excel does not do implicit intersection and will return an array of values from the multicell named range.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest method of accessing data from a multi-celled named range is the INDEX function. For example:

```
=INDEX(AnyNameofMultiCellNamedRange,2)
```

This gives the 2nd value of a multi-celled named range.

```
=INDEX(AnyNameofMultiCellNamedRange,2, 3)
```

In a 2D array, this shows value of the cell on the 2nd row and 3rd column.

In VBA, it is even simpler - you reference it as you would any other array. For example:

```
x = AnyNameofMultiCellNamedRange (2,3)
```

Note that without the (x,y) or (x) reference in brackets after the named range, you're essentially saying "make x = to the entire array".

Answer (score 1):

`=AnyNameofMultiCellNamedRange` is actually returning an array of values.  Depending on the physical location of the formula, you may see one of the values, or the `#VALUE!` error.

To see the individual values, you can either enter it as an array formula over a range of the same dimensions, or you can use the Index function to see individual values.  It will work as required in functions that take array arguments.